# Changes to the Ubuntu Server installer?

Tags: server, system-installation, documentation

I messed up my Ubuntu 18.04.1 installation and decided to reinstall, which meant creating a new USB since I couldn't find the old one. To my surprise, the installer looked completely different than before, and had options it did not have before. For example before where I simply selected one of my  network interfaces, I now choose "create bond" and then select the interface. It also appears that the manual configuration of RAID disks is different now. Unfortunately I don't have pictures from the previous installer, but here is a shot of the new one:[image]

I am confused because this is ostensibly the exact same version that I downloaded before. Where are these changes documented? Were they officially announced someplace?

Comment: Why not just google it? You'd find this: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server#2

Comment: I assume you downloaded from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server. They say _This release uses our new installer, Subiquity. If you need support for options not implemented in Subiquity, such as encrypted filesystem support, the traditional installer can be found on the alternative downloads page._ Download the ISO with the traditional installer from here instead https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads#alternate-ubuntu-server-installer Make sure the ISO does not contain _live_ in its name because that is the one using Subiquity.

Comment: OK, I did miss that part on the download page, thanks.